# sudo apt-get update -f not working

Tags: apt, package-management

Whenever I am trying to fix the broken package it is throwing the following errors.

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libidl-2-0 libkeybinder0 liborbit2 libvte-common libvte9
  linux-headers-4.13.0-32 linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic python-gconf python-gnome2
  python-keybinder python-notify python-pyorbit python-vte
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
455 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 408140 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Many of the answers in that link are recipes for a broken system and do not fix the problem. Best file a bug report so the dependencies can be resolved.

Comment: This fixed my issue `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install kde-config-telepathy-accounts` Thanks N0bert

Comment: IMO that is a horrible fix =)